# How to replace IndexOutOfRangeException error and use BadRequest() instead in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my asp.net core project I have method which I am updating string field. I am checking if it is last element I need to show error. But problem is I am getting error as expected:
**System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

My methods looks like:

```
[HttpPost("upgradeproject/{userId}/{projectId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpgradeProject(int userId, int projectId)
{
    var projects = await _context.Projects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 
    projectId);
    var  kube= await _context.Kubesprays.Select(x => x.Version).ToListAsync();
    string[] sorted = kube
        .OrderBy(item => Version.Parse(Regex.Match(item, @"[0-9]+(?:\.[0- 
            9]+)+").Value))
        .ToArray();

    //var res = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sorted);
    var currentVersion = projects.KubesprayTargetVersion;
    var nextVersion = sorted[Array.IndexOf(sorted, currentVersion) + 1];
    var last = sorted.Last();

    if (currentVersion == last)
    {
        return BadRequest("You are already using the latest release"); // want to 
        use this
    }

    if (currentVersion != nextVersion)
    {
        return BadRequest("Upgrade already in progress");
    }

    if (userId != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
        return Unauthorized();

    if (currentVersion == nextVersion)
    {
        projects.KubesprayTargetVersion = nextVersion;

        // Update entity in DbSet
        _context.Projects.Update(projects);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is better to rewrite code without getting Exception and check it in such a way:

```
var currentVersion = projects.KubesprayTargetVersion;
var currentVersionIndex = Array.IndexOf(sorted, currentVersion);

if (currentVersionIndex == sorted.Length - 1)
{
    return BadRequest("You are already using the latest release"); 
}

var nextVersion = sorted[currentVersionIndex + 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want:

```
try
{
    // Whatever you are trying
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
    return BadRequest("Message");
}
```

But better to prevent the exception by coding to check for out of range. Using Linq:
(skip the number of items corresponding to index of version then get next if any)

```
    if (sorted.Contains(version))
    {
       var nextVersion = sorted.Skip(sorted.ToList().IndexOf(version) + 1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
       return BadRequest("Message"); 
    }
```

Comment: version has type string. This code won't work correctly

Comment: This code also won't work correctly. `First()` will return version, not enumerable of versions. You skip first char of this version and take second char

Comment: Edited in a rush to work for string. Last edit gets next version or null :)